# Printing custom errors in assembly

Tags: assembly, error-handling, error-messaging

So I am wondering what the standard way of printing custom errors in assembly is. I do it by simply creating a custom string in the data section and printing it to stderr. Is there a better or more efficient way of doing it? Creating a lot of custom strings seems weird and (to be frank) too easy to be true.

Comment: If you look at compiler output, you'll see that's exactly what they do.  I don't know how else one would do it.

Comment: I see. I asked because it seemed weird to declare a bunch of error strings at the begginging of the program. Seems I was wrong.

Comment: You don't have to put them all at the beginning - a decent assembler will let you switch back and forth between sections, so you can place each one in the source file close to the code that uses it.

Comment: I always put my strings at the end. They don’t have to be declared before use.

Comment: Normally string data can be read-only and thus should go in the `.rodata` section.  (Or `.rdata` on Windows, or maybe other names on other platforms.  `.rodata` is correct for ELF GNU/Linux targets.)